# Are BrE “colour” and AmE “color” two different orthographic words?

Tags: meaning, orthography, is-it-a-word, linguistics

According to *The Longman Student Grammar of English* (Biber *et al*., 2002 Pearson Education ESL), “orthographic words” are words

> that we are familiar with in written language, where they are
>   separated by spaces

The authors then give an example:

> They wrote us a letter.

which contains five orthographic words.

What about words that have the same meaning yet different spelling? Are the examples provided in the title of this question, *color* and *colour*, therefore two different orthographic words?

Comment: They are poorer examples of 'different orthographic words' than 'bow' as in arrows and 'bow' as in genuflection. Many would say they're 'spelling variants of the same word'. But the word 'word' is ill-defined. Probably, David Crystal would say that 'color' and 'colour' are not different lexemes.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Would that apply to **skate** (blade under a foot) and **skate** (flatfish) which have the same spelling and pronunciation but have different meanings and [etymology](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=skate&oq=skate&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.4080j0j4&client=tablet-android-pega&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8)? These seem to be different orthographic words but look and sound identical.

Comment: I'd say so. But if you look up duck[1] and duck[2] at AHDEL, it is arguable that the etymologies are close enough to argue for homonymy rather than polysemy – yet AHDEL gives them as different headwords. // 'Orthographic words' is usually used to disambiguate between say 'ink well' (a compound noun written as two orthographic words) and the solid variant 'inkwell'; they're the same lexeme.

Comment: I deliberately chose skate because both meanings are nouns. I would think that words which appear to be orthographic but are different parts of speech are not orthographic by definition.

Comment: Please, why would you confuse such a simple question even by introducing BrE and AmE , let alone orthographics?

Your initial research should have shown you that neither “color” nor “colour” is strictly a neologism, Anglicism or Americanism. Webster’s and Oxford, for two, acknowledge that both were acceptable; perhaps equally common, in Britain at the time of the American colonisation.

Why each became more popular on one side of the Atlantic is hardly relevant… they are the same word and have always been optional spellings.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Another complication is names that are identical except for different spelling. For example, there is a book called [*The Sun in Splendor*](https://www.librarything.com/work/4873453) and another called [*The Sun in Splendour*](https://www.librarything.com/work/270109). I feel like changing the spelling of either one is not OK, according to which they have different titles. (A tangential comment: one and the same book can have multiple titles. For instance, *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone* was published as *Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone* in the US...)

Answer (score 4):

Tom McArthur, editor of The Oxford Companion to the English Language, says the two variants represent the same orthographic word:

> On occasion, the orthographic word has canonical forms for different
>   varieties within English: BrE *colour* and AmE *color* ('the same
>   word' in two visual forms).

--([Living Words: Languages, Leicography, and the Knowledge Revolution](https://books.google.com/books?id=8eW3PXgaEk4C&dq=%22orthographic%20word%22%20color%20colour&q=canonical%20forms%20for%20different%20varieties#v=snippet&q=canonical%20forms%20for%20different%20varieties&f=false), Tom McArthur, University of Exeter Press, 1998, pg. 45)